# AWS SDK v3 for NodeJS doesn't call Lambda nor returns error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js

I have this Lambda function that calls another Lambda (both in same Lambda application and CloudFormation). Turns out that after lambda.send() is called, the code kind of doesn't proceed method execution. But the code outside scheduleNotification() executes normally. If I check the monitor logs for the notification called inside another function, it shows no calls at all! What am I missing here?
[image: lambda call]
[image: method call]
I've tried calling the function locally, remotely, through AWS console and no changes.

Comment: Use `for...loop` instead of `.map`

Comment: Please do not upload [images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) when asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

In the provided case, when doing a `.map`, you're just creating an array of promises with `scheduleNotification`, but you never `await` any of them. You would need to await them one by one or you can e.g. use a `Promise.all` to then await all of them.